# React component cant fetch data from local JSON file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, components

The following code was working when the const url data was being used and passed in the fetch. I created a Json local file with a different array passed in fetch and now it is not working. Should I re-phrase my code now that it is local and from a URL? The console says "Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React"

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FaAngleDoubleRight } from 'react-icons/fa'
import data from './data.json'

function App() {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState(data)
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  const newJobs = data
  setJobs(newJobs)
  
  const { company, dates, duties, title } = jobs[value]
  return (
    <section className="section">
      <div className="title">
        <h2>experience</h2>
        <div className="underline"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="jobs-center">
        {/* btn container */}
        <div className="btn-container">
          {jobs.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <button
                key={item.id}
                onClick={() => setValue(index)}
                className={`job-btn ${index === value && 'active-btn'}`}
              >
                {item.company}
              </button>
            )
          })}
        </div>
        {/* job info */}
        <article className="job-info">
          <h3>{title}</h3>
          <h4>{company}</h4>
          <p className="job-date">{dates}</p>
          {duties.map((duty, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index} className="job-desc">
                <FaAngleDoubleRight className="job-icon"></FaAngleDoubleRight>
                <p>{duty}</p>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </article>
      </div>
      <button type="button" className="btn">
        more info
      </button>
    </section>
  )
}

export default App;

    enter code here
```

Comment: In the Console Im getting "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is really just JSON data:

```
import data from './data.json'
```

Then this makes no sense:

```
const reponse = await fetch(data)
```

What are you *fetching*?  The data that's already in `data`?  This is *most certainly* failing and there's an error in your browser's development console.  (*Always* check for errors first.)

If you already have the data then you can remove the `fetch` operation, which means you can remove the `useEffect` entirely, and remove the `loading` state entirely.  Just use `data` as the start of your state:

```
const [jobs, setJobs] = useState(data);
```

In fact, if you don't ever *modify* this data and it's always statically displayed then you don't even need the `jobs` state either.  Just use `data` in your render.

Comment: I updated my original post to a new format with your suggestions. Im getting a new error message right now in the console?

Comment: @AlexAmiriyan: Why did you add `setJobs(newJobs)`?  `newJobs` is a reference to `data`, which was already used to define the `jobs` state.  What is the purpose of setting the data to *itself*?  You're updating the state *to itself* on every render, which triggers a re-render, which updates state, which triggers a re-render, etc., etc.  Don't update state on every render.  And there's no need to update state to a copy of itself.

Comment: Ohh now It is working! I get what you mean! I changed the names around and got it to function. Thank you for the help. This was a great learning experience